# Import specific JSON part into a table as rows

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2022

How can I import a specific json section into a table as rows.
The structure of the json file is shown below. Say I only want to import the elements within the Maski element as rows into a new table TMaski.

```json
{
    "naglowek": {
        "dataGenerowaniaDanych": "20240123",
        "liczbaTransformacji": "5000",
        "schemat": "RRRRMMDDNNNNNNNNNNBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB lub RRRRMMDDNNNNNNNNNN, gdzie R to cyfra roku, M – miesiąca, D - dnia daty generowania pliku, N to cyfra NIPu, a B to cyfra rachunku bankowego"
    },
    "skrotyPodatnikowCzynnych": [
        "000002e2f59c240729d0f1c460ac7b58da598792a3ea0c9052a198551fae7f1f976056964a0f4ea2722cfe5149a27a579256688692d9e003157d046daf6cc790",
        "000008a1b847d4fe26fb9ade8a836fb4922d936da15b52dbe22b3192d3dae7aef9b9ace2c59001de8ddd172f51b82eadc47c68a2714d0ad3cabb99ae8e563c1d",
        "00000957b00aca4a0eb09c34040690448337f24999fbe958c287bce4c749e46026fc6e735e9cda3f62ca4e60b4b26c5c9d6e4eca38fcdd2ba2ac2330964458ff"
    ],
    "skrotyPodatnikowZwolnionych": [
        "fffc45a348278154d31e8cae404c4cb3c7e59e4fe0db96a4dc8592c382be7b41d1e7bbd83fad47468431d0b6a5bab51bbeec3e9704045c41ab2b96d8cd2739a6",
        "fffce3e99a75f2ec3ce83a574c8712e8d478ef0d5a91bdb26cc80b83940df0db602520cfa0992ae072518fa98514d5aa78691ff53fe759f618de99b7124e3d70",
        "fffd0eb178fa59b6b9221cdd5ece13494a08ecd480d1c2ef5d003eb92397b7464e1d5dda85e4a19de50b252c53ab8ef198f1133bbc62aebabb99b9dd33480449"
    ],
    "maski": [
        "XX10100055YYYXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "XX10100068YYYYXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "XX10200032YYYXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "XX10200032YYYYXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "XX10200045YYXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    ]
}
```

I got stuck at this

```sql
DECLARE @JSON VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Maski VARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\20240123.json', SINGLE_CLOB) import
SELECT @Maski = JSON_QUERY(@JSON, '$.maski');
```

[query output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4ASm.png)

Comment: Have you had a look at [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OpenJson() for that. ie:

```
SELECT m.Value
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON) AS oj
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(oj.Value) m
WHERE oj.[Key]='maski';
```